# PowerBI using customer %% as X-Axis

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm looking to create a line graph with accumulated revenue and -gross profit as 0-100% Value Lines on the Y-axis and then have 0-100% of the amount of customers on the X-axis.

[image: Example]

I've managed to get the Y-axis and the accumulated lines working using Months on the X-axis. That's not the hard part though, I need to get customer count 0 - 100% on the X-AXIS and I cannot seem to figure it out.

No particular parameters desired i.r.t. the customer accumulation. We just want to be able to see how much the sales are rising along with the relative distinct count of customers in our database.
This way we can see that the first 20% of customers hold i.e. 50% of the revenue etc.

It's a bit weird, I've tried adding custom columns to calculate the percentage of a customer to the grand total of distinct counts but I cannot seem to get it to accumulate. Perhaps i'm looking entirely in the wrong direction and there's a better solution to this. I'd appreciate any help!

KR,

Maarten

Comment: If your set of customers is fixed, then a calculated column can work. Do you need to dynamically filter the customer population (e.g. with slicers)?

Comment: To start off, a fixed set of customers would be sufficient. But I can't even seem to get that to work properly. (to become a 0-100% X-axis descended from big to small customer to ensure the accumulated revenue line goes 0-100% as well as seen in the pic) Thank you in advanced Alexis Olson

Answer (score 1):

You can make the x-axis as a calculated column. If you don't already have a Customer dimension table, then you can create a new calculated table as follows:

```
CustomerAxis = 
VAR CustomerRev =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        DISTINCT ( Data[Customer] ),
        "CustomerRevenue", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Data[Revenue] ) )
    )
VAR TotalRev = SUM ( Data[Revenue] )
VAR TotalCustomers = DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[Customer] )
VAR CumulativeCols =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CustomerRev,
        "CumulativeRevenue",
            SUMX (
                FILTER ( CustomerRev, [CustomerRevenue] >= EARLIER ( [CustomerRevenue] ) ),
                [CustomerRevenue]
            ),
        "CumulativeCount",
            COUNTROWS (
                FILTER ( CustomerRev, [CustomerRevenue] >= EARLIER ( [CustomerRevenue] ) )
            )
    )
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        CumulativeCols,
        "% of Customers", DIVIDE ( [CumulativeCount], TotalCustomers ),
        "% of Revenue", DIVIDE ( [CumulativeRevenue], TotalRev )
    )
```

Then you can drag and drop these last two `%` columns into a line chart to get the desired curve.

[image: Screenshot of visual]

PBIX file I created: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6trky7t0h42gkp/Pareto.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Hi Alexis, thank you kindly. Just want to let you know. I've read it last night and made a start. Couldn't quite get it to work yet as the values of revenue were incorrect but the customer axis method works great. Thank you. I'll keep working on it and will update here when I hopefully have succesfully recreated your solution.